# angular - how costly are pipes for more complex transformations

Tags: performance, angular, angular-pipe

I have an array of tasks and "taskstore" which looks like this

```
tasks:Task[]=[...]

interface Task{
    title:string,
    deadline:Date
}

taskStore$ = new BehaviourSubject<Task[]>(this.tasks)
```

Now I want to display the tasklist with multiple filter options.
Sorting after the deadline is quite straightforward e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let task in tasks | sortyByDay='ascending'"></<div>
```

In the pipe using underscore.js (and ignoring the order option here)

```
transform(tasks:Task[]): any {
        return _.sortBy(tasks[])
    }
```

Now I want to transform the simple tasklist into something like

```
taskDaylist:Taskdaylist=[...]

interface TaskdayList{
    day:Date;
    tasks:Task[]
}
```

In order to be able to display lists with list header which sums up the tasks of a day (like number of tasks, or total duration like in toggle)

This would involve multiple sorting and mappings inside the pipe.

I would like to know how it will affect the performance if I'd do this inside a pipe, instead of e.g. a service and then .next() the result.
The pipe is obviously more reusable more easy to implement than a service.

Comment: All pipes are run when change detection is done. So they need to be quick and simple.

Comment: what if i'd be using OnPush change detection?

Comment: Keep in mind that OnPush prevents change detection on children in the view and not content, but the inputs of that component are still checked. But if the parent component is also OnPush then you might be okay.